# How can i use nested where conditions in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, conditional-statements, nested-attributes

is it possible to not just to apply multiple where conditions but nested ones?

like:
`conversations.where.not(:sender_id => current_user.id).messages.last.content`

i want to access not only the conversation with the sender not being the current user but the nested messages which are associated with the conversation.

is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

```
Message
  .joins(:conversation)
  .where.not(conversations: { sender_id: current_user.id })
  .last
  .content
```

Comment: thanks for your response, can you explain your code? `messages.joins(:conversation).where.not(conversations: { sender_id: current_user.id }).last.body` is not possible

Comment: In my code, I assumed that `Message belongs_to :conversation` and `Conversation has_many :messages`. If that's true it should work for your case

Comment: the association is correct but if i try it like you suggested, there are no messages available while `current_user.messages.joins(:conversation).where.not(conversations: { sender_id: current_user.id })` does give me a ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation, i cant access the actual content

Comment: @GabrielTheCoder `ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation` means you get the collection of ActiveRecord, well, records. It means ***it is*** working. Now just do what you asked for - `.last.content`

Comment: `.last.content` returns a no method error, even though there is a column calles "content". Just `.last` returns nothing oO

Comment: Please, show me what you query exactly and what exactly you get

Comment: `<%= current_user.messages.joins(:conversation).where.not(conversations: { sender_id: current_user.id }).last.content %>` in my view

Comment: im sorry, `undefined method 'content' for nil:NilClass`. in fact there is a column for content ... thats why i think thats weird.

Comment: @GabrielTheCoder because `last` returns nothing. Meaning, there are no messages for conversations, where sender id is not current_user's id.

Comment: thats why i am stuck, in fact there is a conversation where the sender (initiator of conversation) is not the current user

Comment: The query is correct. Check the data until you find the issue

Comment: i found a workaround but i moved on. thank you anyway